# Black border all around simulation / viewport in iOS using Xamarin + CocosSharp

Tags: ios, cocos2d, xamarin

I'm just getting started with Xamarin and CocosSharp so it's possible I've missed something basic here.. but whatever it is I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to get my app/game to be fullscreen (I would prefer to see the status bar with connection, battery, and time.. but for now I'll settle for just full screen.

I'm editing this line:

```
CCScene.SetDefaultDesignResolution(1080, 1920, CCSceneResolutionPolicy.ShowAll);
```

And I've tried a bunch of different resolutions, but no matter what I do I can't get it to use the entire screen. As you can see in the image below, even if I enter a very large value for the height, it still does not use up the free space.

How do I make it so the game uses the entire screen, and if possible shows the statusbar?

If it makes any difference the program is set to portrait only.

[image]

Comment: You mean Cocos2d, right? I had the same issue. Turned out I had forgotten to scale my background image sprite. I also needed to scale it up a few notches so that it was large enough to fill the screen.